# Creating a login using sql in java

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, authentication

I am trying to figure out why my code is getting sent to the exception catch block and how to make this part of my log-in work correctly. The problem seems to be in Class.forName(driver);  While debugging I noticed that I get an error, "variable source not available, source compiled with-out g-option". Is this the reason my code will not move onto the next step? if it is what do I need to fix it, and what does it mean?

I do have imported in my program.....

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

 private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        try {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1.mdb";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
        st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("it actually ready this set of code!");
        String un = UserName.getText().trim();
        String pw = Password.getText().trim();
        String sql = "select user,pass from Table2 where user='"+un+"'and pass='"+pw+"'";
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        int count = 0;
        while(rs.next()){
            count = count+1;
        }
        if (count==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User, Found Access Granted!");
        }
        else if (count>1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicate User, Access Denied!");
        } 
            else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user doesn't exsist. ");
             }

        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("exception 2 ");
        }

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Did u add sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver jar in your class path?

Comment: If it's getting "sent to the exception catch block", you should get the stack trace for more details. Change the catch block to `System.out.println("exception 2", ex)` to get the stack trace and then update your question with it.

Comment: You should add sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver jar to your class path

Comment: Try removing **.mdb** from **String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1.mdb";**

Comment: I know this may sound silly (please forgive me I am new)  how would I add "sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver " into my class path?

Comment: Which java Runtime you are using? Java 7 or Java 8?

Comment: I am using java 8. (sorry I had to remember how to find that file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing .mdb from `String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1.mdb";` 
and simply write `String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";`

This might work for you!

**Note this is gonna work on or below Java runtime 7 only**
Since **Java 8**, the JDBC-ODBC Driver support has been **removed**. You can still do [something like this](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to connect to MSAccess DB if you want.

Alternatively, you can use one of the many databases for which free JDBC drivers are available, like MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer etc.

Comment: I did make the change you suggested, and thank you for pointing this out.   I am still getting the error. While debugging, the error is happening before I get to this string. The problem is at "Class.forName(driver);" I just don't know how to get it to go past this line of code.

Comment: Which JDK version you are using? 7 or 8?

Comment: I am using java 8 ( sorry had to remember where to find the file )

Comment: Then you cant access MS Access, visit the link i provided in the answer above, download those 4 jars, add it in your library and things will work for you. Alternatively, download lower version of Java

Comment: You know I think your right I might need to try using one of those other options mentioned above. I had no idea my method was no longer supported.  I suppose I need to find another way to accomplish this. Also using one of your suggested options listed above. Thank you! You have been very helpful.

Comment: @CAPTiNDANCE Anytime mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Get database connection object as below:

```
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=db1.mdb;";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

Also add code to print exception stack trace:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("exception 2 ");         
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do the ex.printStackTrace(); I wasn't sure how to do that ( though I wanted to ) I will attempt what you have posted here. and see how that works out.

Comment: ok I have made adjustments to how this is Written. I am now getting the following errors:

Comment: it won't let me post all of the errors so I will post the first 2 since I think the are relevant. atjava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=db1.mdb; java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

Comment: @captindance : Go through this link for Java 8 JDBC-ODBC : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc>